# Copying a randomly generated string from python to the clipboard

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, clipboard

I'm working on a "Password Generator" that will generate a string of random characters. I would like to add a 'Copy' button that when clicked will take that random string and add it to the clipboard so that it can be pasted elsewhere.

I thought I had it worked out with my current code as I stopped getting error messages but whenever I try to paste the password I get something like "<*function genpass at 0x029BA5F0*>".

```
import random
from swampy.Gui import *
from Tkinter import *
import string
#--------Globals-------
pcha = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
g = Gui()
#--------Defs---------
def genpass():

    return "".join(random.choice(pcha) for i in range (10))

def close():
    g.destroy()

def copy():
    g.withdraw()
    g.clipboard_clear()
    g.clipboard_append(genpass)


#--------GUI----------

g.title("Password Helper")
g.la(text="Welcome to Password Helper! \n \n Choose from the options below to continue. \n")


rndpass = StringVar()
update = lambda:rndpass.set(genpass())

btna = g.bu(text="Generate a New Password", command=update)
btna.pack(padx=5)

pbox = g.en(textvariable = rndpass)
pbox.config(justify='center')
pbox.pack( padx = 5)

btnb=g.bu(text ="Copy to Clipboard", command=copy)

btnc=g.bu(text ="Exit", command=close)

g.mainloop()
```

I feel like I'm missing just one little thing that would solve my problem but I just can't guess what it is. I've been searching around and found a few possible solutions (even pyperclip) but no matter how I try them I always end up with the same outcome. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
g.clipboard_append(genpass)
```

is adding the *function* `genpass`, rather than its return value

You need to *call* the function with `()`:

```
g.clipboard_append(genpass())
```

---

**Edit:** It looks like you're storing the password in `rndpass`. So to get that back out, you need to call `rndpass.get()`:

```
g.clipboard_append(rndpass.get())
```

Comment: This helped, but now instead of just adding the already generated password (that shows in the entry field) to the clipboard it generates a completely new password and adds that instead.